# How to edit shared preferences in an activity other than the one it is created in?

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences

I have created some shared preference in an activity and I want to modify it in a broadcast reciever...How can I do that??? Please help...

I have tried looking but couldn't get the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
```

using the context passed into the BroadcastReceiver.